# update value for a key in dictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I want to update value for key 'distance' in a dictionary which is not Mutable, I have an array consist of dictionaries which is read from json, I need to update all distance values in app, could you please provide me by a sample code that how can I do this?

here is where I create this array:

```
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    self.seachResult =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:nil error:nil];
```

and here is sample information in it:

```
2013-07-20 00:04:41.753 MyApp[61075:16a03] sorted array of dictionaries: (
    {
    cid = 2;
    distance = 0;
    image = "http://images.png";
    latitude = "48.245565";
    longitude = "16.342333";
    manual = "";
    movie = "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v";
    pcode = 023942435228;
    pid = 1;
    pname = "example product";
    price = "12.00";
    qrcode = "";
    rid = 1;
    rname = "Example Retailer Name";
    sale = 0;
    "sale_percent" = 0;
    "sale_price" = "0.00";
    text = "here is text about sample product number 1...\nasdasdasda\nsdfsdfsd\nSdfsdf
},
    {
    cid = 1;
    distance = 0;
    image = "";
    latitude = "";
    longitude = "";
    manual = "";
    movie = "";
    pcode = 1;
    pid = 3;
    pname = "test product";
    price = "46.00";
    qrcode = "";
    rid = 2;
    rname = "";
    sale = 0;
    "sale_percent" = 0;
    "sale_price" = "35.00";
    text = "some text here...

},
    {
    cid = 2;
    distance = 0;
    image = "httpestImage";
    latitude = "48.245565";
    longitude = "16.342333";
    manual = "";
    movie = "";
    pcode = 1;
    pid = 2;
    pname = "sample product 2";
    price = "126.00";
    qrcode = "";
    rid = 1;
    rname = "Example Retailer Name";
    sale = 1;
    "sale_percent" = 20;
    "sale_price" = "99.99";
    text = "here is text about sample product number 2...\nblah blah blah\nasdasdasd\nASdasdas\nASdasdasd";
}
)
```

for test I tried this but even I cannot update value for such a simple dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];
[dict setValue:@"test" forKey:@"key2"];
```

error:

2013-07-20 00:46:08.086 NSdictionaryTest[61130:11303] *** Terminating app due to    uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryI 0x7556390> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key key2.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c90012 0x10cde7e 0x1d18fb1 0xb79e41 0xafb5f8 0xafb0e7 0x2200 0xf31c7 0xf3232 0x423d5 0x4276f 0x42905 0x4b917 0xf96c 0x1094b 0x21cb5 0x22beb 0x14698 0x1bebdf9 0x1bebad0 0x1c05bf5 0x1c05962 0x1c36bb6 0x1c35f44 0x1c35e1b 0x1017a 0x11ffc 0x1e5d 0x1d85)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: You are initializing the NSMutableDictionary *dict with an immutable one. 

This should work: 

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary   dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      @"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];
    [dict setValue:@"test" forKey:@"key2"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the dictionary returned by JSONObjectWithData use the NSJSONReadingMutableContainers option.  This causes the method to return mutable container classes.  eg:

```
self.seachResult =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Comment: I read about 'NSJSONReadingMutableContainers' but I don't know how to use it? can you please provide me by a sample code?

Comment: See the updated answer.  Just add that as an option to your call to JSONObjectWithData.

Comment: it seems it works but I have a problem my distance value is an integer but when I want to update it I have an error which says'Impilicit conversion of int to id disallowed with ARC'.
how can I fix this?
[[self.seachResult objectAtIndex:0] setValue:23 forKey:@"distance"];

Comment: you can't put integers into a dictionary, only objects.  Stick the integer inside NSNumber, eg: [myDict addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:23] forKey:@"integerKey"];

Answer (score 2):

Is there any particular reason you need to use an immutable dictionary ?

You could use a [NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

I guess self.seachResult is your NSDictionary, you can simply declare it as NSMutableDictionary.

Initialize it with:

```
self.seachResult = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];
[self.seachResult addEntriesFromDictionary: NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:nil error:nil]]; 
[self.seachResult setObject:YOUR_UPDATED_VALUE_HERE forKey:@"distance"];
```

additionally you could also create a new NSMutableDictionary and fill it with the entries from the non-mutable one like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableSearchResults = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[self.seachResult count]];
[mutableSearchResults addEntriesFromDictionary: self.seachResult];
[self.seachResult setObject:YOUR_UPDATED_VALUE_HERE forKey:@"distance"];
```

and if you want to return again an immutable one, you can just do this:

```
[mutableSearchResults copy];
```

I hope it helps.
Please note I just typed the code here in SO editor, so I might have misspelled some.

Comment: Thanks for codes, self.seachResult is an array I tried to modify your code to work fr it but as I am beginner couldn't do it, can you please update for code with assuming that self.seachResult is an array not dictionary?!
and you wrote 'dictionaryWithCapacity:10' but number of items depends on query and json data

Comment: [self.seachResult setObject:YOUR_UPDATED_VALUE_HERE forKey:@"distance"]; doesn't work, I updated question can you please check it?

Comment: @John sorry my bad, I did not notice self.searchResult was an array.
NSDictionary increases automatically its size if needed, even thought on a mobile phone is always better to try to initialize it with the expected size and now that you mention self.searchResult is an array the best it to initialize it like this:
    self.seachResult = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[self.seachResult count]];
I will edit my answer based on your comments.

Comment: Thank you very much unfortunately I don't have enough credit to vote up

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary is immutable (cannot be changed after it has been created). Have a look at NSMutableDictionary instead. BTW -- it's easy to create an NSMutableDictionary from an NSDictionary.

Comment: could you please provide me by a sample code how to create NSMutableDictionary from an NSDictionary ?

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];

Comment: Or [myImmutableDictionary mutableCopy];